# How to submit a form/list using pagination to the controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, pagination, asp.net-core-mvc

When I click to go to the next page I want the user's selections (tags selected and recipes displayed per page) to be sent to the controller so that the next page displays the recipes with the filters applied.

Currently, when I select tags (foods/ingredients) and search for recipes containing these tags, I'm able to keep the other user's selection of the number of recipes to be displayed per page and vice versa, however when I change page via pagination I lose what tags where selected by the user, however I do keep how many recipes to display per page (`pageSize`), as I pass this to the controller via the Anchor tag of each page

```
    @*Pages*@
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.AllRecipes, page => Url.Action("Index", new
{
    page = page,
    pageSize = Model.PageSize
})
```

[image: Display of the page]

I would think I would need to submit the form when/on changing the page, as you can't pass a List of the tags selected (`Model.AllTags`) to the controller?

Thank you

```
<form asp-action="index" method="get" id="FindRecipesForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    @* Select Tags*@
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="list-group col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <li class="list-group-item active" style="z-index: -10;">
                All tags
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.AllTags.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="AllTags[i].TagId" type="hidden"> <input asp-for="AllTags[i].Name" type="hidden">
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="AllTags[i].isChecked">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.AllTags[i].Name)
                    </label>
                }
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    @*Sort and Filter - Open side panel button*@
    <div class="sort-filter-mobile">
        <button type="button" class="sort-filter-mobile-btn" onclick="openNav()">Sort and Filter</button>
    </div>

    @*Side Panel - Sort and Filter - Mobile*@
    <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel" @*style="display:none;"*@>
        @*Top banner*@
        <div class="top-banner-sort-filter-mobile">
            <button class="sort-filter-close-btn" type="button" onclick="closeNav()"></button>
            <span class="refine-results-mobile"><strong>Refine:&nbsp;</strong>@ViewBag.NumRecipes results</span>
        </div>
        <div class="search-mobile-wrapper">
            @*Clear all button*@
            <button type="button" class="clear-all-search-btn-mobile">Clear all</button>
            <div class="pt-3">
                @*Recipes per page*@
                <div class="sorting-wrapper">
                    <label class="sort-and-result-label" for="results-per-page">Results per page</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PageSize, Model.PageSizeList, new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @*Side Panel - Sort and Filter - Mobile- End*@

    @* View Recipes*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (ViewBag.Tags != "")
        {
            <p class="search-results">Search results for <span class="text-primary">@ViewBag.Tags</span>  (@ViewBag.NumRecipes results)</p>
        }
        else
        {
            <p class="search-results">Search results (@ViewBag.NumRecipes results)</p>
        }
    </div>

    @*Grid*@
    <div class="grid">
        @foreach (var recipe in Model.AllRecipes)
        {
            <div>
                <img class="recipe-image" src=@recipe.ImageURL style="" />
                <div class="display-recipe-name" @*style="border: solid black 1px; "*@>@recipe.Name</div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    
    @*Search Recipes*@
    <div class="form-group mt-1">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @*Page and Recipe search result details*@
    Page @(Model.AllRecipes.PageCount < Model.AllRecipes.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.AllRecipes.PageNumber) of @Model.AllRecipes.PageCount - <span style="color:darkblue; font-weight:600">@ViewBag.NumRecipes Recipes</span>

    @*Pages*@
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.AllRecipes, page => Url.Action("Index", new
{
    page = page,
    pageSize = Model.PageSize
}),
        new X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
        {
            //DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
            ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "Navigation" },
            LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
            PageClasses = new[] { "page-link" },
        });
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.AllRecipes, page => Url.Action("Index", new
> {
>     page = page,
>     pageSize = Model.PageSize
> }),
>         new X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
>         {
>             //DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
>             ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "Navigation" },
>             LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
>             PageClasses = new[] { "page-link" },
>         });
> ```
>
> however when I change page via pagination I lose what tags where selected by the user,

The issue relates to above code (the paging link), as we can see from the above code, the paging link's URL only contains the page and pageSize parameters, instead of contains the selected tags, so, after click the paging link, the selected tags will not pass to the action method.

To solve this issue, you could refer the following steps to modify your code:

1. In the Index action method, add a selectedtags parameter to receive the selected tags.

   When you click the "Sort and Filter" button, I suppose you will submit the form to the Index action method, then you could get the selected tags, and transfer the selected tags to the paging link using ViewBag or ViewData.

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, int pageSize, string selectedtags)
    { 
         ...

         //Check if selectedtags contain value, if contains value, according to it to filter data.

        //After submitting the form, you could get all selected tags and add a separator 
        //Transfer the selected tags to the paging link using ViewBag

        //var tags = 
        //if (tags!=null && tags.Length >0)
        //{ 
        //    ViewBag.SelectTags = string.Join(",", tags);
        //}

        return View(recipes.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
   ```
2. In the Index.cshtml page:

   ```
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.AllRecipes, page => Url.Action("Index", new
    {
         page = page,
         pageSize = Model.PageSize,
         selectedtags = ViewBag.SelectTags
     }),
   ```

Then, after rendering, the paging link like this:

```
`<a href="/Foods?page=3&amp;selectedtags=Apple%2CBanana%2CPinapple">3</a>`
```

Besides, you could also use JQuery to get all selected tags, and add the selected tags at the end of the paging link's url (as the parameters). Then, in the Index action, receive the selected tags and based on it to filter data.